# Add the ability to tag an answer differently than the question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tags on answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/tags-on-answers)

Sometimes an answer can be categorized in a way that the question cannot.  For instance, a question may be about using javascript to solve a problem and an answer may suggest a jQuery solution.  I think it would be useful to be able to tag answers, then provide the ability when viewing a question to filter the answers by the tags.  Using the above example, I may be interested in only seeing (or not seeing) solutions that are tagged with jquery.  The tags on the answer would, by default, be those on the question, but they could be updated when the question is initially submitted or later on via the edit function.

Comment: You know, someone is going to develop an irration fear of organization  from all these tags.

Comment: I'm for this, just because I don't think Rich B is busy enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think that considering the potential usage of it, it is something which may be too much bother to deal with. What about people who have interesting or ignored tags, should the answers show up differently (or not at all) if the user tags his answer differently?

One could possibly say that you could institute the same ideas just by incorporating the "tags" into your post (example: "This deals with jQuery") and then anybody who is interested only in jQuery answers can just do a Ctrl+F and search for the terms you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to resurrect this question but I just came across a good usage for tagging an answer.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8701763/823393) I have posted code that implements a `dawg` structure along with a lock-free version. Perhaps SO's indexing has not completed its sweep yet but searching for `[java] lock free dawg` does not find it.

I would like to vote for adding tags to answers because tags are **key** words, not just attributes of the content of the answer.

Comment: `[java] +lock +free +dawg` finds it. Things like this is one reason why I've always disliked the way SO search is using OR instead of AND by default.

Comment: @hammar - So user would only find it if they knew exactly what they were looking for. Hmmm...