# The mystery of the tagged answer - and more

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question, data-dump, views

It is (currently) [not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1024/tags-on-answers) [possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14241/add-the-ability-to-tag-an-answer-differently-than-the-question) to tag answers. Yet, if I query [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), then [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript/310914#310914) *does* have a tag, namely `javascript`. I'm at a loss: how did that happen?<sup>†</sup>

```
SELECT Id, Tag FROM Posts, PostsTags 
WHERE Posts.PostTypeId = 2 AND Posts.Id = PostsTags.PostId
```

**Edit:** The are also five answers ([207](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176/apache-php-error-log-per-virtual-host/207#207), [936](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935/string-literals-and-escape-characters-in-postgresql/936#936), [950](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194/upgrading-sql-server-6-5/950#950), [111111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-does-a-javascript-closure-work/111111#111111) and [512673](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512266/java-multiply-operation-behavior/512673#512673)) with a view count of 1 instead of 0:

```
SELECT Id, ViewCount FROM Posts WHERE PostTypeId = 2 AND ViewCount <> 0
```

These results also hold through at least January 10.

---

<sup>†</sup>: `PostTypeId = 2` means that the post is an answer, not a question (`PostTypeId = 1`).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible through the interface, but you are talking about a database, that can be manipulated directly.

Most likely a test they did in the past, that they forgot to remove

Answer (score 0):

That post points to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript/310914#310914).

Comment: I linked to that answer as well. The question is: what makes it so special?

Comment: Great question. Didn't see your link to it in your post.  The trick is to retag the question and see if that affects anything. :-)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Ok, I tried retagging it, will see if solves issue at next SEDE update. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267700/why-is-there-an-answer-in-the-so-database-that-has-tag-data-attached#comment868121_267700 Will upvote your comment if does :)

Comment: Did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a sub product of an hypothetical question/answer merge?

Otherwise, this might be a good old plain bug.