# Why is there an answer in the SO database that has tag data attached?

Tags: discussion, tags, answers, data-explorer

[I found an answer in Stack Overflow's database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/310914/456814) through SEDE that has a non-null value of "JavaScript" in the Tags column (query below),

```sql
SELECT -- TOP 5
  p.Id AS [Post Link],
  p.Tags,
  p.PostTypeId,
  ph.*
FROM Posts p INNER JOIN PostHistory ph ON ph.PostId = p.Id
WHERE PostTypeId = 2 AND Tags IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ph.CreationDate ASC
```

and for the lazy (aren't we all?), [here's a clickable query link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/373865).

A `PostTypeId` of 2 corresponds to answers, [as documented here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/163250). This is *the only answer* in the entire database that has a non-null tag. It's not supposed to have a tag, right? Does anyone have a clue about how this happened?

**Updated info**

I just queried the database with

```sql
SELECT *
FROM PostTags
WHERE PostId = 310914
```

and it resulted in an empty set, so at least according to *that* table, the answer has no tags.

Comment: Probably just a developer error; I see a revision on the post by a developer with a 1 character change that might be related.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [this revision by Oded](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/310914/19). The revision shows up in my query too.

Comment: Unfortunately the duplicate doesn't have a satisfactory answer. It might have been a bug with the auto community-wikification…all sorts of weird behaviour in the early days.

Comment: @TimStone I blame the Illuminati...more on that to follow soon...

Comment: So I added a couple tags to the question to see if it will solve this issue, as stated by George Stocker [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38305/the-mystery-of-the-tagged-answer-and-more#comment83931_38307). The SEDE will be updated in about 15 hours (if doesn't bork itself again), so we can rerun query to see if issue resolved then.

Comment: Didn't work :( :(