# How can I see the average and median question scores for a given tag on a given SE site?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, statistics, score

How can I see the average and median question scores for a given tag on a given SE site? E.g., what is the average and median score for the questions that have the tag [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) on Meta.SE (I took this example randomly, no particular interest in it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The median is easy to find. Go to a tag and sort by score. The median will be on the middle page, so approximately [page 743 for bug questions with the default 15 questions per page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug?tab=votes&page=743&pagesize=15), which shows the median as 5.

The average (mean) would require using SEDE. I wrote [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1776742?TAG=bug), which you can plug your own tags into. If I'm correct, it comes out to slightly over 7 for bug questions.

Comment: Doesn't the `posts` table include both questions and answers, though? I believe the dump also contains deleted questions.

Comment: @tripleee There's only [one answer that has tags in the DB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38305/323179). And I'm querying `Posts` not `PostsWithDeleted`.